# Strings, Vectors, Parsing, Converting

Tags: c++, string

I would like some help in trying to create a set of string variables which are dependent on string with even length. So, one would be given the string `str0`, which has size, say 100, and I want to store every two cells in `str0` in another string called `str1`, and so on; that is, if I let

> str0 = "8517009663267111443765353568345207927294601110028317841194534479270436162474731520343936822627589531";,

then I would like somehow to have a gadget which pushes every two digits in `str0` into a another string called `stri` where `i` is the nth two-digit combo in `str0`, namely we would have

> str1 = "85";
>
> str2 = "17";
>
> str3 = "00";
>
> str4 = "96";,

and so on. But this would change in accordance with the size of the input string (`str0`), so every time the user runs it she/he can stream different sized strings to produce a set of `str0.size()/2` string variables. The whole idea here is that I'm trying to convert these strings `str1`, ..., `strn` into integers in a for loop or something later on, but I can do that myself.

Comment: Liberties? Just read the question *very* carefully, and I think you'll manage. o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming str's size is even

```
vector<string> result;
size_t n = str.size() / 2;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
    result.emplace_back( str.begin() + i * 2, str.begin() + i * 2 + 2 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is quite helpful.